# Non-Blocking Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am re-factoring a C# project that is used by several full-sized applications.  This class interacts with hardware and often takes hundreds of milliseconds or more to execute some commands.  In many cases, I am replacing Thread.Wait() calls that the previous programmer wrote with ThreadPool calls to perform these actions.

Now, some of the functions this project provides to the several projects using it take hundreds of milliseconds or more to execute *and* return a value to the calling program that the program must use.  My question is whether or not there is some mechanism that I may use within this project to make these calls execute and return on some thread other than the main thread?  In other words, I want to make these methods non-blocking from the perspective of this project, rather than require other applications using these functions to place calls in a separate thread.

Thanks

Comment: this is a very vague question, but you might want to look into [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: Are you allowed to change your external interface, or does it have to work without modifying your 'full-sized applications'? Not sure if you can achieve what you want without changing the interface. If you can, there's the async/await pattern (.net 4.5), or any kind of async event based pattern (.net <= 4.0)

Answer (score 5):

> In other words, I want to make these methods non-blocking from the perspective of this project, rather than require other applications using these functions to place calls in a separate thread.

In general, the best approach is often to return a `Task<T>` in this type of scenario.  This allows the caller to block if necessary, or use the new `await` and `async` keywords to cleanly coordinate with your library, without blocking or forcing them to move to a separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .net 4.5 you can use `Task.Run` to execute the slow operations on a separate thread and then `ConfigureAwait(false)` to not execute on the main thread once they return.

```
Task.Run(() => <slow operatoion).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what version of the framework you're using, have a look at the begin/end async pattern. You should look at changing the API for the project to implement it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx

Comment: The APM model is really out of date - using `Task<T>` is better for new libraries, as it provides all of the benefits, none of the drawbacks, and future proofs the API much better...

Comment: @ReedCopsey - I realise it's a 'mature' pattern. Task<T> was introduced in v4.0 of the framework. The project referred to is an existing one which could very well be pre-4.0.

Comment: Even if you have to support .NET 3.5, the EAP pattern typically replaced the APM pattern until .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

i worked on similar stuff ... i would suggest you to use 'select' instead of using threading.... look at this ... if it helps you

http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html